# docker: Check space left on volume from container

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-container

I have a volume mounted in a container. The volume is of fixed size and the container writes data to this volume. How can I check the space left on the volume from within the container.

I can run commands on host running docker, but is it possible to do this from inside the container where the volume is mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically get the capacity as you would do in a normal Linux machine: `df -h` executed inside the container:

**Prerequisite A:** create a fixed size volume

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=tmpfs --opt device=tmpfs --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 fixed-size-volume
```

**Prerequisite B:** Mount the volume in your container wherever you need you mountpoint to be (`/var/fixed-mount-point` in my example)

```
docker run -it --rm --mount source=fixed-size-volume,target=/var/fixed-mount-point  alpine sh
```

**Step 1:** List the mounts inside the container and filter by the name of the mount point(I am already with a terminal inside my container since I used -it. To open a terminal you can use `docker exec -ti <containerID> sh`

```
/ # df -h | grep fixed
tmpfs                   100.0M         0    100.0M   0% /var/fixed-mount-point
```

**Step 2:** Create a dummy file in the mount point: I used dd to create a 1MB file

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/fixed-mount-point/file.txt count=1024 bs=1024
```

**Step 3:** Check again the capacity of the volume. Note the change from 0% to 1%

```
/ # df -h | grep fixed
tmpfs                   100.0M      1.0M     99.0M   1% /var/fixed-mount-point
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create the volume with the following command:

```
docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=tmpfs \
--opt device=tmpfs \
--opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
data_vol
```

You can run a docker using volume (the shell command is for simulate data creation):

```
docker run --name vol_test --rm -v data_vol:/data busybox sh -c "while true; do df -h | grep /data ; sleep 1; dd if=/dev/zero  bs=1M  count=1 >> /data/test;done"
```

And you can follow the volume evolution from outside as well using exec:

```
docker exec vol_test df -h | grep /data
```